# What tool in Flet was used to make these tabs?

Tags: python, flet

There's a program like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVxKN.png). It is written in Python, using the Flet library. What was used to make all these tabs-windows? I have looked through all the documentation and found nothing similar. All these tabs can be moved with the mouse.

I've read all the documentation but haven't found anything similar

This is what it looks like when you're moving [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqXDz.png)

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow. I think it is a combination of https://flet-controls-gallery.fly.dev/utility/draggable and a custom layout

Comment: It may be useful to include what the program is and who created it.